# OnTaskFailed event handler in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

If I use **OnError** event handler in my SSIS package, there are variables **System::ErrorCode** and **System::ErrorDescription** from which I can get the error information if any things fails while execution.

But I cant the find the same for **OnTaskFailed** event handler, i.e. How to get the **ErrorCode** and **ErrorDescription** from the OnTaskFailed event handler when any things fails while execution in case we want to only implement OnTaskFailed event handler for our package?

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful, it's a list of all system variables and when they are available.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141788.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into the same issue, and I've worked around it by :

1. Creating a @[ErrorCache] variable
2. In my case the task was being retried multiple times, so I needed an Expression task to reset the @[ErrorCache] variable at the beginning of each retry
3. Create an OnError event handler, which contains an Expression task purely to append the @[ErrorMessage] to the @[ErrorCache]
4. Create an OnTaskFailed event handler which then utilises the @[ErrorCache]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the event handler of the task you want to monitor for errors and click on the link to create a new handler.
Then create a task like Send Mail and create 2 variables: mail_header and mail_body. 
**IMPORTANT**: Move the variables from the current scope to the *OnError* scope otherwise the values won't be available when processing the package.
Define the mail_subject variable as string and set the expression as: "Error " +  @[System::TaskName] + " when executing " +  @[System::PackageName] + " package."

Define the mail_body variable as string and set the expression as: REPLACENULL( @[System::ErrorDescription],"" ) + "\nNotify your system administrator."

On the task editor, create an expression assigning Subject to the @mail_subject variable.  Define the MessageSourceType as a variable and set MessageSource to the @mail_body.

Answer (score -1):

In the task that you put on the error event handler you can select parameters that are only available in an error handler such as system:Errordescription or system:Sourcename (which provideds the task that it failed on). We use these as input variables to a stored proc which inserts into an error table (and to send an email for a failed process) that stores other information beyond just the logging table. We also use the logging table to log our steps and in clude on error in that so general error information goes there.

Comment: thanks, as the System::ErrorDescription variable is not available for OnTaskFailed, Then whats the purpose of using OnTaksFailed i.e. What are the things which we log with OnTaskFailed event handler ?

Comment: We don't use Ontaskfailed, so I don't know. On error seems to grab everything we need.

Comment: What about when placing an error handler on a data flow task - if you use the OnError event it will raise a number of errors for the child and parent data flow tasks and therefore execute the condition multiple times. The OnTask failed event executes once, but does not have access to the ErrorDescription variable. How can you get around this?